# substitution for googleperf tools that works on 64 bit Linux

Tags: c++, google-perftools

As some of you might know Google provides for free great collection of tools for analyzing  c++ code:
http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/

Problem is that there is apparently some libunwind problem on 64 bits, and authors can't do anything on their side to fix it(

> But I don't expect a
>   fix anytime soon: it depends on the  libc folks and the libunwind
>   folks working out some locking issues.  There's  unfortunately not
>   much we ourselves can do.

), so I'm searching for replacement. 
Is there any similar tool that provides cool graphical representation of profiling data(for example: [image])

)

EDIT: paste from README that explains the problem:

> 2) On x86-64 64-bit systems, while tcmalloc itself works fine, the
>   cpu-profiler tool is unreliable: it will sometimes work, but sometimes
>   cause a segfault.  I'll explain the problem first, and then some
>   workarounds.
>
> Note that this only affects the cpu-profiler, which is a
>   google-perftools feature you must turn on manually by setting the
>   CPUPROFILE environment variable.  If you do not turn on cpu-profiling,
>   you shouldn't see any crashes due to perftools.
>
> The gory details: The underlying problem is in the backtrace()
>   function, which is a built-in function in libc. Backtracing is fairly
>   straightforward in the normal case, but can run into problems when
>   having to backtrace across a signal frame. Unfortunately, the
>   cpu-profiler uses signals in order to register a profiling event, so
>   every backtrace that the profiler does crosses a signal frame.
>
> In our experience, the only time there is trouble is when the signal
>   fires in the middle of pthread_mutex_lock.  pthread_mutex_lock is
>   called quite a bit from system libraries, particularly at program
>   startup and when creating a new thread.
>
> The solution: The dwarf debugging format has support for 'cfi
>   annotations', which make it easy to recognize a signal frame.  Some OS
>   distributions, such as Fedora and gentoo 2007.0, already have added
>   cfi annotations to their libc.  A future version of libunwind should
>   recognize these annotations; these systems should not see any
>   crashses.
>
> Workarounds: If you see problems with crashes when running the
>   cpu-profiler, consider inserting ProfilerStart()/ProfilerStop() into
>   your code, rather than setting CPUPROFILE.  This will profile only
>   those sections of the codebase.  Though we haven't done much testing,
>   in theory this should reduce the chance of crashes by limiting the
>   signal generation to only a small part of the codebase.  Ideally, you
>   would not use ProfilerStart()/ProfilerStop() around code that spawns
>   new threads, or is otherwise likely to cause a call to
>   pthread_mutex_lock!
>
> --- 17 May 2011

Comment: You really want to be a programmer but don't have the patience to spell out "you"? How will you ever be able to use templates? :-)

Comment: I use " u " for " you " and " _u " for " u ". Regarding templates I have a book. "Advanced C++ MP". It sucks BTW:)

Comment: it works here fine on 64bit.. maybe just some specific libc versions are affected

Comment: @yi -added more info in the Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) has a collection of great tools, including [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#callgrind) to profile the code. The gui client for the callgrind and cachegrind is [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).